# Nikon D5200 sharpness issue

Tags: video-quality, nikon

I've recently been experimenting with the video feature of my D5200 and noticed this issue with the sharpness of the recordings:

**2x video crop screenshot:**
[image: video crop]

**2x photo crop screenshot**
[image]

As image width is limited on stackexchange you may want to look at the screenshots in an extra tab for the full resolution. Both shots were taken using the exact same camera settings. I scaled the photo to match the video and I don't think it was sharpened while downscaling. Oh and by the way, I am using the 40mbps firmware patch, but I don't think that should decrease video sharpness.

Has anybody got an idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's simply because the photo was shot in a much higher resolution than the video. Even though they were downscaled to the same resolution, a (previously) higher-resolution image will look better in this situation in the same way that a clip shot in 4K will look better on a 1080p monitor than a clip shot in 1080p on the same monitor.